# Probability of a random point to be on middle of radius in circle

Tags: probability

A point is selected at random from the interior of a circle $x^2 + y^2 =4$.What is the probability that the point is in middle of any radius?
Thanks in advance for upcoming answers.

Comment: What is your difficulty?

Comment: i was thinking like it should be (2*3.14*1)/3.14*2*2. but i am dividing perimeter by a area which is not a unitless value and probability should be unitless .Please correct me .

Comment: Right, you should divide area by area; what is area of circumference?

Comment: what does mean by area of circumference?

Comment: If you say at random do you mean that your random point follows a uniform distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by "in middle of any radius"? The point will almost certainly be _somewhere_ between the endpoints of _some_ radius -- the only other places it could be are the exact center of the circle and the edge of the circle.

Comment: There is zero probability that the random point is exactly halfway between the two endpoints of some radius, because to be there, the point would have to be exactly on the edge of the circle of radius $1$ concentric with the larger circle, and the area of the edge of a circle is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR as stated $0$.

But you probably want to answer
$$
\mathbb{P}(||z||_2 < 1) = ?
$$
where $z$ is a point inside the circle.

Then the answer is indeed a ratio of areas, i.e. the probability to fall inside the circle of radius $1$ vs. the whole probability to fall inside the circle of radius $2$.

$$
\mathbb{P}(||z||_2 < 1) = \frac{\pi}{4\pi} = \frac{1}{4}
$$

Comment: what does mean by P(||x||2 <1)?

Comment: basically this is norm-2 of the point, i.e. Euclidean distance between point $z$ and the origin. $||z||_2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, where $z = (x, y)$ - a point in the plane.